# How to use constructor injection CDI with a JNDI resource?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, constructor-injection

I'm trying to figure out how to use constructor injection in CDI where one of the parameters is a JNDI lookup.

With normal field injection, I can do the following:

```
@Stateless
public class Publisher
{

  @Inject
  @JMSConnectionFactory("java:/jms/remoteCF")
  private JMSContext context;

  @Resource(lookup="java:global/remote")
  private InitialContext externalContext;

  private Topic genericTopic;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init(){
       try {  
            Object obj = externalContext.lookup(TOPIC);  
            genericTopic = (javax.jms.Topic) obj;  
       } catch (NamingException namingException) {  

       }  
  }
}
```

However, I would like to switch this bean to constructor injection.  Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to create a constructor which injects my `externalContext` resource, given that it is a JNDI lookup.

Example:

```
 @Inject
  public Publisher( @JMSConnectionFactory("java:/jms/remoteCF") JMSContext context,  @Resource( "java:global/remote") InitialContext externalContext ){
      this.context = context;
      this.externalContext = externalContext;
  }
```

But `@Resource` is not an allowable annotation as a parameter.

How can I specify that the `externalContext` parameter is a bean retrieved via a JNDI lookup?  Where do I specify the JNDI name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Create an injection point for your topic using a qualifier.  Something like:

`@Produces
@Named(TOPIC)
public Topic findTopic(JMSContext context) {
    return context.createTopic(TOPIC);
}`

and then inject that into your constructor

2. Create a producer field/qualifier for your `InitialContext`.

`@Produces
@Named("someName")
@Resource("java:global/remote")
private InitialContext externalContext;`

Comment: Thanks - I had to reread this a few times to understand how this worked, but I think I understand.  However, from what I understand the #2 member field has to be a static field.

Comment: No, neither is a static field.